# Модератор удалил из ответа важный дополнительный контекст

Tags: поддержка, answers, moderation, specific-question

Из ответа [Гендерно-нейтральные и небинарные местоимения](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/456273) был удалён важный контекст. В комментариях модератор не реагирует.

Далее следует разбор по пунктам всех претензий, которые прозвучали в адрес удалённого абзаца.

> Просьба воздержаться от излишней полемичности

"Полемичность" — это просто спор при обсуждении вопроса. Спор правилами не запрещён, и вообще в споре рождается истина. Давать несколько ответов с различными мнениями на один вопрос — это распространённая практика на сайтах сети SE и всегда приветствуется.

> в вопросе не спрашивается про данный сайт и обсуждать его здесь ни к чему

Обсуждение контекста, в котором возник вопрос, имеет большое значение. Необходимость соблюдать правила о гендерной нейтральности в речи, когда они несовместимы с языком (о чём сказано в самом популярном ответе), но всё равно должны соблюдаться, рождает канцелярные решения, подобные описанному мной. В отрыве от контекста они непрактичны и бесполезны, но в данном контексте они приобретают важную функцию: соблюдать несоблюдаемые правила.

> очень рад, что вы пытаетесь придумать контекст за меня, но я задал вопрос, потому что хотел узнать про гендерную нейтрализацию языка в общем, а не в контексте "что они там впишут в правила"

Тем не менее, мой ответ отвечает на поставленный вопрос и описывает контекст, в котором подобное решение имеет смысл. Так как ответ пишется не только для автора вопроса, а для всех посетителей, то предоставлять дополнительную информацию является нормальной практикой на всей сети SE.

> Спрашивают про местоимения, а вы про SO, скобочки и т.п.

По каждому пункту из удалённого текста:

1. "SO" — это необходимй контекст, потому что вопрос возникает как необходимость соблюдения спущенного сверху правила, независимо от его рациональности и возможности реализации в языке;
2. "Скобочки" — это признание автором ответа визуальной отвратительности получающегося текста, чтобы читатели не подумали, что он подобный канцелярит одобряет;
3. "Мя и тя" — это шутка; шутки всё ещё не запрещены (к слову, эти местоимения, во-первых, имеют богатую историю, во-вторых, используются до сих пор в различных контекстах).

По совокупности я не вижу в удалённом тексте нарушения правил и даже отхода от сложившихся на сайтах сети Stack Exchange практик. Прошу восстановить удалённый текст.

Answer (score -3):

1. Полемика не запрещена, если она не превращается в спор ради спора. Подобный троллинг уже неуместен.
2. Контекст не имеет никакого отношения к тематике русского языка и будет неинтересен уже через пару месяцев, независимо от принятого решения.
3. Не надо додумывать проблему там где её нет. Ни автор не спрашивал по SO, ни читатели. Я рад, что вас волнует развитие нашего сайта, но вопрос не про него.
4. То что вы не считаете скобки приемлемым вариантом видно и из оставленной части ответа, а "мя" и "тя" имеют смысл только как раз в рамках выдуманного вами контекста.

Comment: 1. Почему вы обвиняете меня в "споре ради спора" и "троллинге"? Вы предполагаете злые намерения. 2. Будет ли контекст важен через месяц — будет видно через месяц. 3. Вы не можете знать мысли всех читателей, поэтому не надо решать за них, что для них важно. Даже если правило не будет введено, оно может быть введено на совершенно другом сайте, и контекст "надо, потому что надо" будет актуален. 4. Вы искажаете мои слова. Я против не любого использования скобок, а против их злоупотребления в канцелярской форме.

Comment: 1. Скорее во флейминге, ваши упоминания сайта никак не помогают разобраться в вопросе, но порождают дополнительную дискуссию. 2. Он не актуален даже сейчас. 3. Вы тоже, в любом случае при общении на "Вы" проблем соблюдения гендерной нейтральности нет. 4. Именно это и понятно из оставшейся части ответа, остальное лишнее.

Comment: 1. Я объясил в исходном посте, почему контекст важен. Вы полностью игнорируете эти аргументы. Дискуссию порождает только ваша цензура. 2. Вы не можете этого знать. 3. Ваше мнение о полном отсутствии читателей, которым интересен контекст, опровергается одним контрпримером. Мне его привести, или вы поверите на слово, что такие люди есть? 3.1. Нейтральность "Вы" в соответствии с новыми правилами — это ваше личное мнение, и оно ничем не подтверждено. 4. В оставшейся части ответа нет ни моей оценки "скобочной" практики, ни обоснования необходимости в ней. Вы это всё удалили.

Comment: @Athari 1. Я объяснил почему не важен. Дальше обсуждать это не вижу смысла. 2. Вы тоже. 3. Такие читатели безусловно есть, но в данном вопросе этот контекст может породить лишь ненужные споры. 3.1 В русском языке пол проявляется в прилагательных, глаголах единственного числа прошедшего времени, местоимениях 3-го лица и некоторых обращениях. При общении на Вы всё это использовать не обязательно. 4. Если считаете, что ваша мысль недостаточно ясна, можете исправить своё сообщение, так чтобы в итоговом тексте не было упоминаний сайта

Comment: 1. Вы не ответили, вы повторили изначальное мнение. Мои аргументы вы полностью проигнорировали. 2. Но если что-то *может* понадобиться, то лучше упомянуть, чем не упомянуть. 3. "Может породить споры" — это не причина для удаления. Этот сайт слишком мёртв, чтобы на нём что-то породилось, будем откровенны. 3.1. Это аргументы, но будут ли они приняты при обновлении правил — вы не знаете и знать не можете. 4. Упоминание сайта не запрещено правилами. "Абстрагирование" слишком усложнит суть и отвлечёт от главных мыслей.

Comment: @Athari 1. Я ваши аргументы прочитал, но не считаю убедительными. 2. В контексте вопроса этого не нужно. 3. Я и не удалял ваш ответ, я убрал ненужные отступления от вопроса. 4. Главное в ответе - это ответ на вопрос, а не ваша полемика о нормах поведения в сообществе.

Comment: 1. "Не считаю убедительными" — это не контр-аргумент. 2. Что такое "не нужно"? Я считаю, что нужно, вы считаете иначе. Так или иначе, это сводится к пункту №1, то есть к вашему игнорированию аргументов железным "не убедил". 3. Вы удалили важную часть, испортив качество ответа. Про "ненужность" — см. п. 1. 4. Вы видите спор о нормах там, где его нет. Я не призывал никого что-либо делать по поводу норм и вообще обсуждать их.

Comment: Ну, вот мы и пришли к логическому завершению спора. Каждый остался при своём мнении.

Comment: Это не логическое завершение спора, это полное игнорирование вами моей аргументации.